# Sony VAIO PCG-K215M laptop screen

Tags: display, sony-vaio

its an old laptop but when i boot it up on the laptop screen it loads the bois screen but when starts to load windows it turns off laptop screen,
i reinstalled xp on it and and the screen works up till drivers get installed

the display driver is ATI Radeon IGP 343M that instaled

cheers

Answer (score 0):

First try to see if the same problem appears if you boot ubuntu live cd. If yes, try some other RAM modules, sometimes they can go bad and if your graphics card shares memory with your system, problems like yours appear...

Comment: hi got ubuntu live cd and it boots off it u get the screen askin to run without installion or to install when chose run without install it goes to another screen for a few seconds with the curors flashing then the monitor turns off, also go some other memory and taken the 2 out that was in this and tryed this other in both slots and still same and sorry its an ati radeon igp 345m

Comment: It seems that your graphics card is dead. Are there any problems found if you run the memory test from the live cd? (Boot cd and select Memory test after the language selection, and let it run for at least half an hour)